# OpenGL 3.2 GL_INVALID_ENUM on glTexImage2D( GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D ... )

Tags: opengl

I am converting an engine from OpenGL 1.1 to OpenGL 3.2.  The following throws a GL_INVALID_ENUM, but I cannot figure out why.

I am calling glGetError() prior to glTexImage2D() to clear it.  When I am done, glGetError() is returning GL_INVALID_ENUM.

```
      glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
      glTexImage2D( GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_2D,   // target
                    0,                     // level
                    4,                     // internalformat
                    32, 32,                // width & height
                    0,                     // border
                    GL_RGBA,               // format
                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,      // type
                    NULL );                // pixels
```

Comment: If it helps, I am running on Mac OS X 10.8.4.  I am running with an OpenGL 3.2 core context. OpenGL version string: 3.2 NVIDIA-8.12.47 310.40.00.05f01

Comment: Why do you use 4 for the internal format instead of a symbolic constant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass in a real `internalFormat`.  I think the pure channel count method was deprecated at some point.

Comment: Although it is likely that this causes the error, it should be an INVALID_VALUE - at least according to the TexImage2D man page. Could be a bug in the man pages though.

Comment: Yep, the 3.2 core spec backs you up on that, page 133.

Comment: IMHO, it should really be an INVALID_ENUM that's generated since the only thing you're allowed to pass to the function is a symbolic constant. It's inconsistent the way it is.

Comment: If I had my way, if you didn't use a sized internal format, that'd generate an INVALID_ENUM too :)

Comment: Changing the internalformat from 4 to GL_RGBA was it.  Annoyingly, the man pages that ship with Mac OS state "Must be 1,2,3 or 4, or one of the following symbolic constants".  So, that's not accurate.

Comment: @mlabbe: Is it possible that OS X ships with two sets of man pages? It ships with two separate OpenGL headers, and you have to include a different one if you want OpenGL 3.2. This could be down to the fact that the platform supports two implementations of OpenGL; I'd prefer to read the man pages on http://www.opengl.org/registry - in particular look for the "Reference Pages". You can get the man pages for a specific (major) version of the API you are targeting this way.

Answer (score 2):

Your internal format, "4", doesn't seem to be a valid format. For example, `GL_RGBA` is defined as 0x1908.

Comment: It is a valid format, but only for compatibility (or pre-3) contexts (but even then it is highly deprecated and strongly advised against).